# OWASP zap-api-scan.py url exclude

Tags: owasp, zap

1. Can zap-api-scan.py take an OpenAPI Yaml file and not just an OpenAPI JSON file
2. Can I exclude specific urls from the scanned API paths ? I tried adding the command something like (really not sure about the format, did some extensive googling on it).This is the closest I came up with:
   -z -config globalexcludeurl.url_list.url.regex=https://10.0.10.130/api/v2/api-docs' (failed to work)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Here are some of the ones we use in our unit tests: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/master/addOns/openapi/src/test/resources/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/openapi/v2
2. I would exclude those URLs from the Scanner rather than globally (as I'm not sure the OpenAPI add-on will obey that). https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/globalexcludeurl/ Pro tip - test this using the ZAP desktop, its much easier to see whats going on. Then its relatively straight forward to conver that into command line options.

Comment: Thanks Simon,  I was actually wondering about how to do it using the zap-api-scan.py and not from the UI desktop app as we are using that flavour of Zap scan.

Comment: Oh yes I realised that, but I still recommending testing with the desktop so you can see whats going on. Then you can convert that into options for the packaged API scan.

Comment: @SimonBennetts I'm curious about that (anything related to making GUI scans work in CLI), if you ever make some examples they would be highly valuable, none seem to exist on the web!

Comment: @TonyNarlockexamples will come in time. If you have specific questions then the best place to ask them is on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users